# Problem with for-loop with character list in r

Tags: r, for-loop, logistic-regression

I need to run multiple logistic regression with only one predictor changing each time (other covariates remains the same). I tried to use a for-loop in R.

I receive this error message that I don't understand:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = VD ~ v + covar1 + covar2 + covar3, : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'v')
```

Here is my code (in reality, I have more than 3 variables to model, but let's say I have only 3):

```
var_list <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

mydata$covar3 <- factor(mydata$covar3)

for (v in var_list) {
  
  results <<- glm (VD ~ v + covar1 + covar2 + covar3, 
                data = mydata, family = "binomial")
  
}
```

I checked that the length of each variable was the same (it was!).

Only covar3 is categorical; covar1 and covar2 are numeric variables.

When I run the same code outside the loop, say for var1 only, everything works fine. How does my loop create this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer that I posted with my close vote, to loop through a list of independent variables we can build an expression with the required variable, then evaluate it as part of an `apply()` function to generate the regression models.

We'll use `mtcars` with `lm()` for a reproducible example, but the same approach will work with `glm()`.

```
# list of independent variables
indepVars <- c("cyl","wt","am")

# use eval() to access the value of x within the formula

theModels <- lapply(indepVars,function(x,dfname){
     lm(paste("mpg ~ ",eval(x)," + disp"),data = dfname) 
},mtcars)


# assign names to list
names(theModels) <- indepVars

# print the first model
summary(theModels[["cyl"]])
```

The tricky part is that we use `eval()` to evaluate the independent variable name passed as `x` to `lapply()` within a `paste()` function that creates an expression. Then we use  that expression within an `lm()` function.

...and the output:

```
> summary(theModels[["cyl"]])

Call:
lm(formula = paste("mpg ~ ", eval(x), " + disp"), data = dfname)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4213 -2.1722 -0.6362  1.1899  7.0516 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 34.66099    2.54700  13.609 4.02e-14 ***
cyl         -1.58728    0.71184  -2.230   0.0337 *  
disp        -0.02058    0.01026  -2.007   0.0542 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.055 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7596,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
F-statistic: 45.81 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.058e-09
```

Answer (score 0):

When we make a regression in R, usually we don't have to adjust different models when we have a categorical predictor. So, try:

`results <- glm (VD ~ v + covar1 + covar2 + covar3,  data = mydata, family = "binomial")`